# Cannot get image in facebook graph comment

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I am accessing facebook through graph api with php, version 2.2.
When a user writes a reply to a comment and attaches an image I dont know how to get a hold of the image!? I cannot see any info regarding the image in the api.

First I read the feed:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/' . $pageid . '/feed?since=' . $dat );
```

Then I access comments for the feeds:

```
 $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/' . $c_id . '/comments' );
```

($c_id = 809559325802038_809564295801541)

The api returns:

```
    [data] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 809559325802038_809565162468121
                [from] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 100002418214924
                        [name] => Conny Olsson
                    )

                [message] => nice
                [can_remove] => 1
                [created_time] => 2015-04-07T12:25:36+0000
                [like_count] => 0
                [user_likes] => 
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 809559325802038_809573482467289
                [from] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 100002418214924
                        [name] => Conny Olsson
                    )

                [message] => ok
                [can_remove] => 1
                [created_time] => 2015-04-07T12:51:52+0000
                [like_count] => 0
                [user_likes] => 
            )

    )
```

The comment on facebook has an attached image:
*https://www.facebook.com/vetgirignu/posts/809559325802038?comment_id=809564295801541*

According to the documentation the attachment tag should be included?!
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/comment

How can I get the image for the comment via gragh api?

Comment: Can you file a bug report for this at developers.facebook.com/bugs?